# Compute sum of Observable<{v: Observable<number|undefined>}[]>

Tags: rxjs, observable

I want to compute the sum of `Observable<{v: Observable<number|undefined>}[]>` in Rxjs.
Sum should always reflect the current state (ie update when an item is removed from the list, or a newly added/existing one is edited.

I have come up with the following sulution, which seems to do what I want, but I do not fully understand why it is working, and not sure if it could be improved or not:

```js
myObservable.pipe(
    switchScan((acc, curr) => {
        return combineLatest(curr.map((a) => a.v)).pipe(
            map((values) => {
                let sum: number | undefined;
                for (const v of values) {
                    if (v === undefined) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (sum === undefined) {
                        sum = 0;
                    }
                    sum += v;
                }
                return sum;
            }),
        );
    }, 0),
).subscribe((sum) => {(sum) => {console.log(sum)})
```

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation of your code

To explain it I am using the following observable structure:

```js
private myObservable = of([
    { v: of(1) },
    { v: of(2) },
    { v: of(undefined) }
]);
```

So the `switchScan` operator applies a reducer function to `myObservable`. A reducer function loops over an array, does something to each item in combination with the previous "sum" and returns the new "sum".
in your case the reducer function takes an initial value, which is 0 as you defined and takes the content of `myObservable` which would be

```js
[{ v: of(1) }, { v: of(2) },{ v: of(undefined) }]
```

Next you use `combineLatest` which takes an array of observables, waits until each observable emits a value and create a new observable from it. You map the observables correctly in order to get

```js
[of(1), of(2), of(undefined)]
```

which is the format you would want to use `combineLatest`. Since all your observables hold an initial value it emits immediately and you get to the `map` operator, which now results in an array of numbers and undefined

```js
[1, 2, undefined]
```

Now you calculate the sum of the observable by using a for loop and return the sum. Which in my case would be 3.

## Simplifed code

```js
this.myObservable
  .pipe(
    switchMap((obs) => {
      const nestedObs = obs.map((a) => a.v);
      return forkJoin(nestedObs).pipe(
        map((val) => {
          return val.reduce(
            (accumulator: number, currentValue: number | undefined) =>
              accumulator + (currentValue || 0),
            0
          );
        })
      );
    })
  )
.subscribe((sum) => console.log('sum', sum));
```

Instead of using `switchScan` you could just use `switchMap`, which switches to the inner observables and does modifications to each emitted value. In your case since there is only one array, this would be the array of observables as in the upper `switchScan`. Now you can map the array of observables the same as you already did.

Next you could use `forkJoin`, which combines an array of observables and emits an array of values in the order to observables in the array were.

```js
[1, 2, undefined]
```

No you can apply a reducer function and calculate the sum of the values in the array. Since you can also have undefined values you have to add the `||` operator, which basically checks if `currentValue` is not undefined or null and otherwise use 0.

Comment: thank you!
I was also looking at `forkJoin`, but it would only work when observables complete, I want it to work on long running observables, and always get the up-to date sum.

Comment: I had the feeling that you wanted live update. I just saw that comment but it's exactly what my answer does

Comment: my observables are actually BehaviorSubjects so data is being modifies over a longer span of time

Answer (score 0):

@JB17 answer is good, but it'll only emit once all the inner observables have completed. If you want instead the sum to be updated as soon as you get a new value, you can do the following:

```js
rx(
  myObservable,
  // when returning an array in a mergeMap instead of an observable
  // it emits each item of the array independently, so here it'll emit Observable<number>
  mergeMap((observables) => observables.map((x) => x.v)),
  // at this stage, we therefore have an Observable<Observable<number>> that we need to unwrap
  // into Observable<number>, and mergeAll is what we need
  mergeAll(),
  // then we accumulate the values using a scan instead of a reduce to have the current sum emitted
  // as soon as there's a new value instead of waiting for all the values to arrive and emit once at the end
  scan((acc, curr) => acc + (curr ?? 0), 0),
  // finally, in case there was a 0 or undefined, we make sure to not emit the same value twice
  distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Assuming the data source would be:

```js
const myObservable: Observable<Array<{ v: Observable<number | undefined> }>> =
  of([{ v: of(1) }, { v: of(2) }, { v: of(undefined) }]);
```

The output is first `1` then `3`.

Here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kdgfhe?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).